# Как организовать загрузку кэша из SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, кэширование, android-shared-preferences

Какое решение будет более корректным относительно архитектуры запросов кэша из SharedPreferences:

1) Для каждого запроса создать отдельный Observable внутри которого строка из SharedPreferences кастуется в класс модели.

2) Для всех запросов создать один Observable , который возвращает строку, а кастовать ее в модель уже в принимающем значение классе.

Comment: вообще SharedPreferences как бы вовсе не предназначены для такого использования.

Comment: @pavlofff , подскажите в таком случае, что предназначено для такого использования?

Comment: Вы что хотите кэшировать?

Comment: Ответы с REST API.